# Identify in list what data is not in UTF-8 format

Tags: python, encoding, chardet

I am ingesting data using CSV files into my my postgres DB through AWS and I am encountering some issues whereby some of the data is not in UTF-8 format.
I want to identify which rows in my data are causing the issue so that I can address at source.

I have been trying to use chardet to give me what I need but can't seem to get it to output the encoding type row by row. I have also tried to used the below which, similar to chardet will tell me if the whole file is a particular encoding or not, but not what rows are causing the issue

```
 import codecs
#PYTHON
encodings = ['utf-8','windows-1250', 'windows-1252'] # add more
for e in encodings:
                try:
                    fh = codecs.open('filename.csv', 'r', encoding=e)
                    fh.readlines()
                    fh.seek(0)
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    print('got unicode error with %s , trying different encoding' % e)
                else:
                    print('opening the file with encoding:  %s ' % e)
                    break
```

any help appreciated!

Example text causing issue below:

> ```
> Aĺi
> Hùssaini
> Buķar
> Falmatàmi
> Mohammad  Bùlama
> Mùstapaha
> Maiďugu
> Shu"ibu
> Aĺi
> Àdamu
> Ja"o
> Khaìcalla
> Makanikì
> Alì
> Mòhammad
> Zaŕami
> Dànkabo
> Kelĺumi
> Umàra
> Goŕoma
> Gaptomì
> Àli
> Àhmed
> Àbdullahi
> Shafi"u
> Mohammed!
> Hassañ
> Aùwal
> Usaìni
> Mohàmmed
> Goniķaka
> Abdullé
> ÑGABGL17401598
> MUSA ĶAUMI
> NGAMCH17051ĺ535
> NGBOJEGB1708ààaaÅQààp
> NGYOGJBY3215`
> NGBOJEAG1709Ź
> ÙNGBOKD1T17090240
> ÑGBOMDMK17100381
> ÑGBOMDMK17100382
> ÑGBOMDMK17100383
> ÑGBOMDMK17100384
> ÑGBOMDMK17100385
> ÑGBOMDMK17100387
> ÑGBOMDMK17100388
> ÑGBOMDMK17100389
> ÑGBOMDMK17100390
> ÑGBOMDMK17100392
> ÑGBOMDMK17100393
> ÑGBOMDMK17100394
> ÑGBOMDMK17100395
> ÑGBOMDMK17100396
> ÑGBOMDMK17100397
> ÑGBOMDMK17100398
> ÑGBOMDMK17100399
> ÑGBOMDMK17100400
> ÑGBOMDMK17100401
> ÑGBOMDMK17100402
> ÑGBOMDMK17100403
> ÑGBOMDMK17100419
> Yyģggghyuuiiiuyttttrrrrrrŕ
> NĢBÒJEGM17100245
> NĢBÒJEGM17100479
> NĢBÒJEGM17100493
> NĢBÒJEGM17100495
> NĢBÒJEGM17100524
> NĢBÒJEGM17100525
> ÑGYOGJGJ122112
> ÑGYOYFKG3824
> Ngyoýfmy4736
> NGBOJEFC1804aaà
> NGBOJEFC1804à8131
> NGYÒGDAKW0717
> NGYÒGDAK20609
> NGBÒMMST19056545
> NGBOMDNY88J00233!!
> ÀNGYOGDAK21907436
> NGBODAAC19110390]
> ```

Comment: you have different encodings inside one csv? could you provide some samples?

Comment: The data is an extract from a system which seems to allow multiple encodings. I don't have control over this system. files are being sent to me with these multiple encodings and I would like to identify those that are not UTF-8. An example of the type of charater that is causing the issue is a funny looking single quote - in the brackets ( ` )

Comment: the backtick is an ascii character... the sample i had in mind was just a small csv with different encoding on each line

Comment: This character  ( ` ) definitely causes an issue. I have isolated this one but need to isolate the others that are causing issues. Attached is a sample of some of the suspected characters - not all will be non UTF-8 but some are.